# Plotting bar and line on same graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I have a data set in an array in Matlab and a point.

I would like to see where the new point stands with respect to the previous data.

I am currently plotting the array using:

```
PreviousPoints=sort(PreviousPoints);
plot(PreviousPoints);
```

The output of which is a graph I would like to add to them a point and make it visible.

If you have any way let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot(1:length(PreviousPoints), PreviousPoints, newx, newy)
```

or

```
plot(PreviousPoints)
hold on
plot(newPt)
hold off
```

(`hold on` will keep plotting things on top of each other until you turn it `off`)

Comment: You can set the color and style of the new point, e.g. `plot(newPt,'k*')`, or you can use the `bar` command (where you will have to pick an `x`, e.g. `bar(length(PreviousPoints)+1, newValue)`